# ABAP Unit Testing - local test class testing a code of other global class

Tags: unit-testing, abap

is there a clean way to write a unit test of a productive code (especially the private methods) of global class `CL_A` from local test class `LCL_B` which is under the global test class `TC_B`? So far I have figured out a trick, which is far from clean coding practice. `TC_B` is a friend of `CL_A` and `LCL_B` is a local friend with `TC_B`. If I want to test method `M_A` of class `CL_A` I have to create extra wrapper method `M_B` in a global test class `TC_B` which calls `M_A`. See a pseudo code sample lower as this could be confusing without structured example.

Thanx!

---

```
CLASS CL_A definition global friends TC_B.
   private:
      METHODS: M_A.
```

---

```
CLASS TC_B definition for testing.
   private:
      METHODS: M_B
         IMPORTING cut TYPE REF TO CL_A.

   METHOD M_B.
      cut->M_A().
   ENDMETHOD.

CLASS LCL_B definition deferred.
CLASS TC_B definition local friends LCL_B.
CLASS LCL_B definition final for testing.
   private:
      DATA: cut TYPE REF TO CL_A.
            env TYPE REF TO TC_B.

      METHODS: test_M_A for testing,
               setup.

   METHOD setup.
      CREATE OBJECTS cut, env.
   ENDMETHOD.

   METHOD test_M_A.
      env->M_B( cut ).
   ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: The clean way be just to to test the public methods. As this not always possible and can sometime makes testing difficult, i use the friend-association also i'm a proponent of clean-code.

Comment: Isn't defining a method of a global test class **private**, overkilling? Anyway, if you really want to make everything private and want to test something private, you don't have a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

[Test publics, not internals](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#test-publics-not-private-internals), because of the detailed reasoning given there.

If not possible, for example because you are caught up in legacy code, establish a global test class that is friends with the original class, and that exposes private methods as public methods.

```
CLASS original_class DEFINITION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS some_private_method ...
ENDCLASS.

CLASS test_wrapper DEFINITION PUBLIC CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS public_wrapper_for_private ...
ENDCLASS.

CLASS test_wrapper DEFINITION GLOBAL FRIENDS original_class.

CLASS test_wrapper IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD public_wrapper_for_private.
    result = some_private_method( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

You can then create a local unit test class anywhere that tests `test_wrapper`.

This solution is fragile and inferior however, and should at most be a temporary means until you get the chance to refactor the original class design.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is meant only as temporary solution. I will keep your advice in mind. Best, R.